# Calling .ToArray on an Enumerable corrupts the Enumerable

Tags: c#, linq, ml.net

I'm not sure if this is specific to ML.NET, but it does happen in the context of it.

I am using ML.NET to classify some images. I realized that it poses a severe difference whether I call `.ToArray()` on the resulting `IEnumerable` or not. The former results in all the array elements becoming identical to the last one.

```
IEnumerable<ImageData> dataCollection = imagePaths.Select(path => new ImageData(path));
IDataView targetDataView = _mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(dataCollection);
IDataView predictionView = _transformerModel.Transform(targetDataView); 
return _mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<ImagePrediction>(predictionView, true).ToArray();
```

In the example shown above, the resulting predictions will all have their image path set to the last image path in `imagePaths`.

I don't believe that this is intended behaviour. What causes this and how can I safely prevent this? For the moment I decided to just not call `.ToArray()`, but I'd like to know more about this issue.

Comment: Does the behavior occur with `ToList()` too?

Comment: @Yennefer Yes, it does. The odd thing is that I am further using the `IEnumerable` later in my code using a `Select` clause, which is working without issues if I don't convert it to an array before.

Comment: Usually, when this happens, is due to a closure over an object instance that is reused. Therefore, deferring the execution of the enumerable, simply yields the last item. What is `GetType()` of `_mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<ImagePrediction>(predictionView, true)`?

Comment: @Yennefer The type is `Microsoft.ML.PipeEngine\`1+<RunPipe>d__3[Application.ImagePrediction]`.

Comment: To whomever voted to close the question, due to more focus being required: Where does the question lack focus? It asks why the array is being corrupted by the `.ToArray()`, which Yennefer explained concisely with their answer. If you still think that I could phrase the question better, I'd gladly accept feedback on that!

Comment: The question does not lack of focus. It is clear enough to have an adequate answer. The action has been reverted back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be in the prediction engine where to limit the memory usage, `row` is reused as per `reuseRowObject`. Therefore when a `ToList()` or `ToArray()` method is invoked, only the last item is used to project the list/array.

```cs
public IEnumerable<TDst> RunPipe(bool reuseRowObject)
{
    var curCounter = _counter;
    using (var cursor = _cursorablePipe.GetCursor())
    {
        TDst row = null;
        while (cursor.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!reuseRowObject || row == null)
                row = new TDst();

            cursor.FillValues(row);
            yield return row;
            if (curCounter != _counter)
                throw Contracts.Except("An attempt was made to keep iterating after the pipe has been reset.");
        }
    }
}
```

The caller is `CreateEnumerable()` where you explicitly set `reuseRowObject` to `true`.

```cs
public IEnumerable<TRow> CreateEnumerable<TRow>(IDataView data, bool reuseRowObject,
    bool ignoreMissingColumns = false, SchemaDefinition schemaDefinition = null)
    where TRow : class, new()
{
    _env.CheckValue(data, nameof(data));
    _env.CheckValueOrNull(schemaDefinition);

    var engine = new PipeEngine<TRow>(_env, data, ignoreMissingColumns, schemaDefinition);
    return engine.RunPipe(reuseRowObject);
}
```

Setting `reuseRowObject` to `false` should solve your issue.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I should really stop thinking of `IEnumerable`s as implicit containers like arrays or lists. So basically the `reuseRowObject` minimizes memory usage, at the cost of not being able to convert the resulting enumerable to a collection?

Comment: In a sense, yes. It depends on how the data is consumed: when the object is reused, it is yielded multiple times, but the "value to which it refers" is changing under the hood. So when the collection is built, technically it contains the same instance over and over. On high performance code, this trick is necessary because the constant allocation adds pressure to the GC and slows down your code, but this implies that you use immediately the value returned. If you want to have a collection, this optimization works against you.